# Performing hypothesis test in R to assess reduced model

Tags: r, regression, multiple-regression, f-test

I have a multiple linear regression model with 10 covariates, and I want to perform the hypothesis test that 5 of the covariates are equal to 0, versus the alternative hypothesis that at least one of them is not equal to 0. More precisely: $$ H_0: \beta_{age} = \beta_{tc} = \beta_{ldl} = \beta_{tch} = \beta_{glu} = 0 \ \text{versus} \ H_1 : \text{at least one} \neq 0$$

So I want to perform this test in the full model using R to discover whether the reduced model which does not include these covariates is preferable to the full model. How do I go about doing this? Below is a summary of the full model in R.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is exactly what an F-test does. What follows depends on the regression models being nested.

Under your null hypothesis, you have a 6-parameter model (five variables and the intercept). You calculate its sum of squared errors, $SSE_0$, via `sum((L_reduced$residuals)^2)`, where `L_reduced` is the `lm` for this model.

Under the alternative hypothesis, you have an 11-parameter model (ten variables and the intercept). You calculate its sum of squared errors, $SSE_1$, via `sum((L_full$residuals)^2)`, where `L_full` is the `lm` for this model.

Let $\sigma^2$ be the error variance and $n$ the sample size. Then under the null hypothesis:

$$ \dfrac{SSE_0 - SSE_1}{\sigma^2} \sim \chi^2_{11-6} \text{ }\text{ }\text{  and  }\text{ }\text{ } \dfrac{SSE_1}{\sigma^2} \sim \chi^2_{n-11}$$

Consequently:

$$ \dfrac{(SSE_0 - SSE_1)/(11-6)}{SSE_1/(n-11)}= F\sim F_{11-6, n -11}$$

You now have a test statistic to compare to $F_{11-6, n -11}$ via `1-pf(F,11-6,n-11)`. This will say if the alternative model holds;$^{\dagger}$ if that is the case, it must be that at least one of those $\beta$ coefficients is not zero. $\square$

All of this comes from chapter 3 of Agresti:

Agresti, Alan. *Foundations of linear and generalized linear models*. John Wiley & Sons, 2015.

$^{\dagger}$ There are the usual caveats about what hypothesis testing means.

Comment: So do I do just compare the F value against the critical F with (11-6,n-11) degrees of freedom? What do choose as n when looking up in a table though? Also, how could I go about finding a p-value for the test?

Comment: $n$ is the number of observations you have, not a value you choose. If you have 1000 observations, you would want to look up in an F-table with 5 and 989 degrees of freedom. You may be more likely to find the critical value for $\alpha=0.05$ (or whatever for 5 and 500 degrees of freedom. If your F-value exceeds that value, you would report $p<0.05$ but could not give a p-value. However, you're using R to fit the regressions. Why not just go with `1-pf(F,11-6,n-11)` to get the p-value?